# Ant build consoles get clobbered by dependent projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, build-process

I have a set of dependent projects in Eclipse, each with its own Ant build script. If I make a change in multiple projects, then select "Build All" (Ctrl+B), each Ant build is invoked in the correct order. But if there is an error in one project, Eclipse still tries to build the other projects also, and in the process clobbers the Ant console so that the build errors are no longer visible. This wouldn't be *quite* so annoying if I could open up the offending project and select "Build Project", but Eclipse out-smarts me: it won't rebuild until I open some file in the project, edit it, and save (typically I add and remove a space character wherever my cursor happens to be). An answer to any of the following questions would be welcome.

How can I configure Eclipse to (in preference order):

1. terminate a "Build All" as soon as any project's Ant build fails?
2. save *all* console output for "Build All" instead of resetting the console for each project?
3. spawn a separate console for each new instance of Ant?
4. allow me to force a "Build Project" even if it doesn't think anything has changed?

[UPDATE] Bonus Question:

- How can I configure Eclipse so that fixing any build errors in a depended-on project counts as a "change" for the purposes of "Build Project"?

Comment: Use Maven and install the m2eclipse plugin

Comment: Haha, I was going to suggest that as well, but there are those who don't\won't use it :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried redirecting standard out to file via a run configuration? A few screen shots to help if not... (you may try 'append' this is not in my screen shot :) )

[image: run config for ant]

[image: Common tag and std io]

Comment: Using "foo.txt", I couldn't find the file afterward. But "${project_loc:PROJECT_NAME}/build.log" works. Unfortunately, the line numbers aren't clickable, as they are in the console.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to have each Ant build log itself, e.g., using the following in `build.xml`

```
<record name="build.log" 
        loglevel="verbose" 
        append="false" />
```

Oddly, Eclipse seems to disable this logging somehow when running an Ant build.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too big on ant, but can't you make the builds dependent on one another?

Comment: There are build dependencies between the projects.