# In Eclipse, with multiple builders on a project, how can I have all build console displayed?

Tags: eclipse, build

Very similar to the #2 option at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703369/ant-build-consoles-get-clobbered-by-dependent-projects-in-eclipse), I'm wondering how I can have all the stdout/stderr output maintained when I have multiple builders for a project.

As it is, each builder clears the console then starts writing its messages to console, but by the end I want to see all the output from all my builders. Logging to a file isn't ideal because my users won't check there.